# ASP.Net MVC: passing parameters as URL

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.Net MVC. I have implemented routing as:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "SearchResult",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{depId}/{empId}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Search", action = "Result" }
);
```

This is how I am calling "Result action of "Search" controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(SearchQueryModel _objQueryStringModel)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Result", "Search", new { depId = "1", empId = "2"});
}
```

It is redirecting me to

```
localhost/Search/Result/?depId=1&empId=2
```

But I want it to be like:

```
localhost/Search/Result/1/2
```

How do I implement correct routing/redirection?

Comment: Is this first route in the `RouteConfig` file?

Comment: Yes. Default route is specified after this.

Comment: I have just tried your route and code and it worked for me.

Comment: And is the method `public ActionResult Result(int depId, int empId)`?

Comment: Yes. It is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You want redirect to route, not just redirect, with your route name in there:

```
return RedirectToRoute("SearchResult", new { depId = "1", empId = "2" });
```

Currently, your code makes use of the default route.

Comment: Is this route specified in an area?

Comment: No. I have written it in RouteConfig.cs under App_Start

Comment: That suggests to me that either your routes config class isn't being called from Global.asax or you have other routes in your application that is preventing it from working.

Comment: Replacing url: "{controller}/{action}/{depId}/{empId}" with url: "Search/Result/{depId}/{empId}" worked for me. I don't know if this is correct way or not though?

Comment: What is the Redirect that you are returning when it works with the route configuration like that?

Comment: return RedirectToRoute("SearchResult", new { depId = "1", empId = "2" });

Comment: Hmmm, there is something funky going on and I can't quite put my hand on it.  I think we need to see your entire route config to get a clear view